# How to store and process possibly duplicate distributed class coupling information in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, boost-preprocessor

I'm writing a `template<class ...Ts> class SortedTypeHolder`. During compile time instantiation `SortedTypeHolder` must collect distributed information about all provided `...Ts` from their headers for future sorting. The gathered information describes which classes depend on others in a form of `template<typename A, typename B> class Pair` specializations. I want to provide multiple dependees for one depender class at once with a macro `DEFINE_PAIRS`.

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
template<class ...Ts> class SortedTypeHolder;

template<typename Depender, typename Dependee>
class Pair : std::false_type {}; //doesn't depend, the default

#define TRUESPEC( _, Depender, Dependee ) \
template<> class Pair<Depender, Dependee> : public std::true_type {}; //depends

#define DEFINE_PAIRS( Depender, ... ) \
   BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH( TRUESPEC, Depender, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_LIST( ( __VA_ARGS__ ) ) )

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

// from A.hpp
DEFINE_PAIRS( A, B, C, D )
// from B.hpp
DEFINE_PAIRS( B, A, C, D )
// from D.hpp. this dependency is reverse yet allowed
//DEFINE_PAIRS( A, D )     //Error C2766 explicit specialization; 'Pair<A,D>' has already been defined

...

SortedTypeHolder<A,B,C,D> holder;
```

I also want my code to allow duplicate dependencies without generating new specializations, but my current realization produces an error in such case. Please give me an advice how do I enhance the code to allow duplicate dependencies.
If it is possible to define multiple `Pair`s at once without macros, it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use function declarations. You don't need to define them, can easily extract the parameter types, can have duplicate forward declarations with no problem, and get ADL for free.

```
void dependency(A, B, C, D); // A depends on B, C, D
```

or, if it's easier to use

```
std::tuple<B, C, D> dependency(A);
```

You'll need to either use SFINAE to handle classes with no dependencies, or have a special guaranteed-worst-match

```
NoDepTagType dependency(...);
```